# E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed without exception message. Will retry token retrieval

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging Services for push notifications in an android app and in MOTO-G5S+, The token does not get generated occasionally. The error I face is

```
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed without exception message. Will retry token retrieval
W/MessengerIpcClient: Timing out request: 1
```

The network connection is fast in both Mobile Data and WiFi Services.
I haven't faced this problem in other devices and Android Emulator.

Is it a Mobile Specific error or a conditional one. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: same issue, any answer?

Comment: in my case i figured out it's because my internet connection, it was too slow so google authentication cannot retrieve the so called token and keep trying: it was as simple as that..Now that my connection is back to normal  everything is ok and instead of "Token retrieval failed without exception message..." i get this: 
D/EGL_emulation(19458): eglMakeCurrent: 0xb43f2fa0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa2ddf3b0)
D/EGL_emulation(19458): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa2c5a4c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa2ddf810)
D/EGL_emulation(19458): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa2c5a4c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa2ddf810)